# Is every element of the range of f(x, y) contained in some level curve of f(x, y)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Is every element of the range of f(x,y) contained in some level curve of f(x, y). Could someone prove or disprove this statement? Intuitively it sounds true but I am not sure.

Edit
Here is the original question, I think the wording is quite confusing.

[image]

Comment: I think there's a type confusion here: what does it mean for an element of the range of $f(x,y)$ (which is a single real number) to be contained in a level curve (which is a set of ordered pairs of real numbers)?

Comment: I am not quite sure of the wording either, but I added the original question if you wanna take a shot at it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is false, because every element in the range of f(x,y) is a 1 dimensional scalar quantity. But a level curve contains (x, y) which is a 2d scalar. Therefore it is false... It was a very tricky question.